# highcharts and django passing a dictionary

Tags: django, highcharts

I'm trying to structure my data for display in a pie chart.

I have a table with Boolean columns: roots, bone, sediment.

I can get the data filtered into a dictionary (in views.py):

```
a = Fraction.objects.values('roots').filter(roots=True)
b = Fraction.objects.values('bone').filter(bone=True)
c = Fraction.objects.values('sediment').filter(sediment=True)
dataset4 = {"roots": a, "bone": b, "sediment": c}
```

it is returned `'dataset4': dataset4,`

In the html highchart code I usually add the data:

```
#views.py
dataset4 = Fraction.objects.values('roots')

#html
  <script>
    Highcharts.chart('container4', {
      chart: {type: 'pie'},
      title: {text: 'Sample Remains'},
      credits: {enabled: false},
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
        {% for entry in dataset4 %}'C {{ entry.roots }}'{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
        ]
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Botany Records',
        data: [
        {% for entry in dataset4 %}
        {{ entry.roots }}
        {% if not forloop.last %},
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        color: 'green'
      }]
```

How do I pass the dictionary object rather than a queryset?

Comment: Could you show the data that in the end is added to the js series object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to modify your query to get the total counts for roots, bone and sediments and then pass those counts to the template:

```
a = Fraction.objects.filter(roots=True).count()
b = Fraction.objects.filter(bone=True).count()
c = Fraction.objects.filter(sediment=True).count()
dataset4 = {"roots": a, "bone": b, "sediment": c}
```

Then in the template, you should be able to create the data for the series by iterating each item in the dictionary, such as this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Botany Records',
    data: [
        {% for name, count in dataset4.items %}
            {name: '{{ name }}', y: {{ count }} }
            {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ],
    color: 'green'
}]
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, the dictionary is fine, but how do I get the dictionary into the pie chart? Whereby the values are grouped/aggregated ie 3 slices: roots, bone, sediment?

Comment: @GaryNobles ok understood. So you're looking to represent the total counts of roots, bone and sediment as a pie chart?

Comment: That's the basic idea, been looking at the documentation, but I'm unsure how the pie chart data is expected to be structured. Lets say there are 10 roots, 10 sediments, 20 bones, so two 25% areas and a 50% area.

Comment: Still having trouble, this is what is returned by your code, which looks right `{name: roots, y: 5 } , {name: bone, y: 4 } , {name: sediment, y: 4 }` but nothing displays. if I change it to `{name: {{ 'name' }},...` then the pie displays but without the name (i.e. root, sediment, bone) so there seems to be an issue getting the name from the dict.

Comment: Ah solved the issue... needs to be `{name: '{{ name }}',...` if you update your answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: @GaryNobles - thanks, missed the quotes around the string. I've updated the answer. Thanks.